# Python flask_mysqldb passing over 10 does't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-mysql

I'm totally new and learning Python+MySQL,
And I have an issue with passing over 10 to %s

```
@app.route('/usr/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def selected_logs(id):
    response_object = {'status': 'success'}
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('''
    SELECT
            usr.id,
            usr.corp_id,
            date_format (log.date, '%%m/%%d/%%Y') AS date
        FROM 
            (usr
            INNER JOIN corps ON corps.id = usr.corp_id)
        WHERE
            usr.corp_id = %s
        ORDER BY usr.id DESC;
    ''', (id))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    response_object['usr'] = results
    return jsonify(response_object)
```

In the URL http://localhost:5000/usr/9 works,
but start to 10... won't work, please help me.

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting
```

THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Execute()` takes an iterable as the second argument. You need to pass an iterable of values to bind to parameters, `(id)` is not an iterable. It is a common mistake to think that it is a `tuple` but it is not, `(id,)` is a `tuple` which is an iterable.

```py
cur.execute('''
    SELECT
            usr.id,
            usr.corp_id,
            date_format (log.date, '%%m/%%d/%%Y') AS date
        FROM 
            (usr
            INNER JOIN corps ON corps.id = usr.corp_id)
        WHERE
            usr.corp_id = %s
        ORDER BY usr.id DESC;
    ''', (id,))
```

The error hides this issue because the `id` value is `'10'` and `str`S are iterables in Python.

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting
```

**Edit:** Response to comment

> although I have still don't understand what you mean completely

`Execute()` takes an iterable of values to bind to parameters in the query, and it must be an iterable in order for `execute()` to support multiple parameters in the query. The only way `(id)` can be an iterable is if `id` itself is an iterable.

```py
id = 9
type((id))
type((id,))
```

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'tuple'>
```

```py
id = '9'
type((id))
type((id,))
```

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'tuple'>
```

The parentheses don't construct a `tuple`, the comma does. Even if you try to create a `tuple` of one element using the explicit, `tuple()` constructor, you'll get an error without the comma.

```py
no_parentheses = 1,
no_comma = (1)
explicit = tuple(1)
type(no_parentheses)
type(no_comma)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'int'>
```

So why did `(id)` work for `id`='9' but not `id`='10'? It's because in each case `id` is a path variable which is a `str` by default and therefore `(id)` is a `str`. Since `str`S are iterable, `execute()` unpacked `(id)` and tried to map it onto the parameters in the query. Since there is only one parameter in the query, the unpacking succeeds for every value of `id` with length=1. When `id`='10', it unpacks as `'1','0'` and `execute()` tries to map it onto two parameters. But, since there's only one parameter, raises an exception:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting
```

I'll agree that this message isn't very descriptive of the root cause here. There may have been more information in the complete stacktrace. Regardless, the important part is "not all arguments converted." It's telling you that there are more values than parameters in the query.

Comment: WOW!! It works. just add ', ' after (id). Amazing!!! Thank you Michael Ruth millions, although I have still don't understand what you mean completely but I'll learn and get it soon. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By reading the error im asumming the id value you are recibing is not the correct data type you need for the evaluation in your query.

Comment: Thanks Cloud89, I've tried ...''', int(id) and in SQL WHERE usr.corp_id = %i , but it doesn't work and gets 'TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable' tried %s doesn't work neither....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).